# Pushing x number of array items to another array conditionally

Tags: javascript

I want to push x number of array items to another array with the condition that the maximum number of items that will be pushed be the difference of `maxPushLimit` (which is 720) and `alreadyPushed` (so if `alreadyPushed` is, say, 300, only 420 can be pushed)

Special conditions:

- If the total of all `alreadyPushed` from `array1` is > total length of `array2`, ignore the last difference (last x items left from `array2`.
- If the total of all `alreadyPushed` from `array1` is < total length of `array2`, last index of `array1` would have redundance (wouldn't be 720, say, 710 if the difference is 10).

I wrote this code to achieve it:

```
const array1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    alreadyPushed: 500,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    alreadyPushed: 600,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    alreadyPushed: 700,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    alreadyPushed: 720,
  },
];

const array2 = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 361; i++) {
  array2.push(i);
}

const maxPushLimit = 720;

let results = [];
let array2Index = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  const array1Item = array1[i];
  const limit = maxPushLimit - array1Item.alreadyPushed;
  console.log(limit);

  if (limit <= 0) {
    continue;
  } else {
    array1Item.array2Items = array2.slice(array2Index, limit);
    array2Index += limit;
    results.push(array1Item);
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Keep in mind that the order of `alreadyPushed` is not important (500, 600, 700, 720 are totally random) 
I want the end result to look like this:

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      alreadyPushed: 500,
      array2Items: {
          // 220 array2Items
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      alreadyPushed: 600,
      array2Items: {
          // 120 array2Items
      }
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      alreadyPushed: 700,
      array2Items: {
          // 20 array2Items
      }
    },
];
```

What I'm getting:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    alreadyPushed: 500,
    array2Items: [
       // 220 array2Items
    ]
  },
  { id: 2, alreadyPushed: 600, array2Items: [] },
  { id: 3, alreadyPushed: 700, array2Items: [] }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the slice operation. It should be `array2.slice(array2Index, array2Index + limit);`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this expression:

```
array2.slice(array2Index, limit);
```

The second argument should not be the *size* of the slice, but the ending index of the slice.

So change to:

```
array2.slice(array2Index, array2Index + limit);
```